# How to stop reloading or retendering the component when using match.params

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have to get the parameter supplied in the URL and do some operation specific to the parameter.
So I have used match.param. and found it is working. But unfortunately my component is rendering or reloading in an infinite loop. How can I stop that.

Sample code which I have introduced for my requirement

```
    const TheBoardSubscription = ({match}) => { 
       const filterIdFromURL = match.params.savedFilterId;
       return (
        <SocketAuth>
          <WebsocketConnectionContext.Consumer>
            {({ addSubscription, removeSubscription, status }) => (
              <ClientContext.Consumer>
                {(value) => (
                  <TheBoardContainer
                    addSubscription={addSubscription}
                    removeSubscription={removeSubscription}
                    status={status}
                    id={id}
                    tenantId={value}
                    filterIdFromURL={filterIdFromURL}
                  />
                )}
              </ClientContext.Consumer>
            )}
          </WebsocketConnectionContext.Consumer>
        </SocketAuth>
      );
    }

    const TheBoardContainer = ({
      intl,
      addSubscription,
      removeSubscription,
      status,
      id,
      tenantId,
      filterIdFromURL,
    }) => {
      .
      .
     return (
      if(filterIdFromURL){
                console.log("this could be the correct place to initiaze savedfilters");
                //const fetchedFilters = fetchSavedFilters(values.savedFilterIds[0]);
                client.query({
                  query: GET_SAVED_FILTER,
                  variables: { id: filterIdFromURL },
                  fetchPolicy: "network-only",
                }).then(
                  resp => {
                    const savedFilter = resp.data && resp.data.getSavedFilter;
                    //console.log("savedFilter data::::", resp.data);
                    setSearchFilters(savedFilter);
          refetch({
                      search: searchFilters,
                    });
    }
                )
              }else{
                console.log("Donot do anything");
              }

)
  .
  .

}
```

Things are working fine for me but the component seems to be rendering in an infinite loop. I did googled for solution but did not understand how to make it. Can someone please help me here.
[image]

Comment: It seems the props of TheBoardContainer Component are updating. setSearchFilters or refetch might be triggering the update. if this is not case then try wrap your component with React.memo(TheBoardContainer);

Comment: defined const MemoizedTheBoardContainer = React.memo(TheBoardContainer); And called MemoizedTheBoardContainer  from TheBoardSubscription like <MemoizedTheBoardContainer
                addSubscription={addSubscription}
                removeSubscription={removeSubscription}
                status={status}
                id={id}
                tenantId={value}
                filterIdFromURL={filterIdFromURL}
              />, still facing the same problem

Comment: TheBoardContainer should return JSX you are using if condition if you want to run JS code then try make this customHook